# \newenvironment behaviour with \begin{landscape}

Tags: environments, tabularx

I would like to use landscape mode for a `\newenvironment{lessonPlanner}` in which I have a table. but I get an error when I embed `\begin{landscape}` and `\end{landscape}` in the begin and end statments of the environment, however If I move the `\begin{landscape}` outside of the environment I dont get the error.

Specifically

```
Runaway argument?
!File ended whlie scanning use of \TX@get@body,
```

I got this once before and had to use the command form of tabular, but I dont know
if this is appropiate for landscape, and I would like to understand the problem better

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Michael

-----------------------example lesson.tex file.---------------------------------

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lessonPlanner}

\begin{document}

\begin{unitPlan}{Principles of nutrition}

% \begin{landscape}
\begin{lesson}{Hunger and Satiety}{14:00}{70}

  \activity{Introduction}{3}{Electronic White Board}{
     Welcome to the class and overview of nutrition with lead in to hunger and Satiety
   }

  \activity{Ghrelin}{10}{Electronic White Board}{
   Discuss  the role of Ghrelin on  the neurochemistry of the brain, and how ghrelin instigates sleep
  }

  \activity{Student quiz}{5}{Electronic voting system}{
    Students are quized on their understanding of Grhelin and its effects on the brain
  }

  \activity{Lesson Close}{3}{}{
    Review briefly the lesson topics and close the lesson
   }

\end{lesson}
% \end{landscape}

% \begin{lesson}{The Macro nutrients}{10:20}{70}
% \end{lesson}

% \begin{lesson}{Vitamins and Minerals}{11:30}{70}
% \end{lesson}

\end{unitPlan}

\end{document}
```

--------- lessonPlanner.sty file -------

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{lessonPlanner}


% \usepackage{pgf}
% \usepackage{paralist}

% \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\RequirePackage{pgf}
\RequirePackage{paralist}
\RequirePackage[export]{adjustbox}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{tabulary}
\RequirePackage{pdflscape}

\newcounter{MinsIntoLesson}

\newenvironment{unitPlan}[1]
      {Start Unit: \textbf{#1} \vspace{2em} } % begin unitPlan
      {}  % end unitPlan

% Start Lesson Title: \textbf{#1} Time Alocation: \textbf{#2} Resources: \textbf{#3}

\newenvironment{lesson}[3]{
%          \begin{landscape} % <- Doesnt work, get error \TX@get@body.
%          \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{c | L | L | L }
              \tabularx{\linewidth}{ c |  c  | X |  c }
                  Time & \mbox{Activity} & Description &  Resources   \\
           \hline
      } % \begin{lesson} 
  { 
\endtabularx 
% \endtabulary
% \end{landscape} % <- Doesnt work 
}  % \end{lesson}

% The following command takes an integer minute value and returns it in hour:min format
\newcommand{\hourFormat}[1]{  
0:{\pgfmathparse{int(#1/10)}\pgfmathresult}{\pgfmathparse{int(mod(#1,10))}\pgfmathresult}
}

\newlength\hunits
\setlength\hunits{3.5pt}

\newcommand{\activity}[4] { %
  \hline \hourFormat{\theMinsIntoLesson}  \addtocounter{MinsIntoLesson}{#2}  
  \rule[\dimexpr9pt-#2\hunits\relax]{0pt}{#2\hunits} &  #1  &  #4  &  #3  \\ \hline % \begin{activity}
}

\newenvironment{activ}[4]{ 
  #1  &  #2  &  #3  &  #4  % \begin{activity}
}{}

\def\hi{Hello, this is my own package}

\let\myDate\date

\newcommand\GoodBye[1][\bfseries]{#1Good Bye}

\endinput

%%
%% End of file `mypackage.sty'.

\newenvironment{lesson}[1]{}The first parameter is  The second parameter is {}
```

Comment: Your package is still providing flat lessons, I see ;).

Comment: It does work, by the way, if you use the command form for `landscape`.

Comment: Thankyou cfr, Ill fix the spelling, and thanks for the tip on hte command form of landscape.

Comment: Is there anohter way around this, as I think I might like to use tcolorbox table ie \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!25,tabularx={ c | c | X | c }, title=table ], but I wind up with the same problem, I have had a look at the tabularx manuals but cant quite figuire out why the error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because the `tabularx` environment scans ahead to pick up the contents to be typeset and needs to see `\endtabularx` directly to effect this.  In your code it is buried in the `\end{lesson}` command.

One good general way around this is to use the `environ` package and its `\NewEnviron` command.  This sets up a new environment but does it in one block of code, with `\BODY` used to insert the contents of the environment.  In your case you can use it as follows:

```
\RequirePackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{lesson}[3]{
  \begin{landscape}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c |  c  | X |  c }
      Time & \mbox{Activity} & Description &  Resources \\
      \hline
      \BODY
    \end{tabularx} 
  \end{landscape}
}  % end lesson
```

Note how this matches normal use in the document of the enclosed code, and in particular that you can now use `\begin{tabularx}...\end{tabularx}` instead of `\tabularx...\endtabularx`.

[image: Sample output]

Here is the full code.  By the way I have consistently written `lessonPlanner` not `lessonPlaner`.

Main file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lessonPlanner}

\begin{document}

\begin{unitPlan}{Principles of nutrition}

\begin{lesson}{Hunger and Satiety}{14:00}{70}

  \activity{Introduction}{3}{Electronic White Board}{
     Welcome to the class and overview of nutrition with lead in to hunger and Satiety
   }

  \activity{Ghrelin}{10}{Electronic White Board}{
   Discuss  the role of Ghrelin on  the neurochemistry of the brain, and how ghrelin instigates sleep
  }

  \activity{Student quiz}{5}{Electronic voting system}{
    Students are quized on their understanding of Grhelin and its effects on the brain
  }

  \activity{Lesson Close}{3}{}{
    Review briefly the lesson topics and close the lesson
   }

\end{lesson}

\end{unitPlan}

\end{document}
```

`lessonPlanner.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{lessonPlanner}

\RequirePackage{pgf}
\RequirePackage{paralist}
\RequirePackage[export]{adjustbox}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{tabulary}
\RequirePackage{pdflscape}
\RequirePackage{environ}

\newcounter{MinsIntoLesson}

\newenvironment{unitPlan}[1]
      {Start Unit: \textbf{#1} \vspace{2em} } % begin unitPlan
      {}  % end unitPlan

% Start Lesson Title: \textbf{#1} Time Alocation: \textbf{#2} Resources: \textbf{#3}
\NewEnviron{lesson}[3]{
  \begin{landscape}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c |  c  | X |  c }
      Time & \mbox{Activity} & Description &  Resources \\
      \hline
      \BODY
    \end{tabularx} 
  \end{landscape}
}  % end lesson

% The following command takes an integer minute value and returns it in hour:min format
\newcommand{\hourFormat}[1]{  
0:{\pgfmathparse{int(#1/10)}\pgfmathresult}{\pgfmathparse{int(mod(#1,10))}\pgfmathresult}
}

\newlength\hunits
\setlength\hunits{3.5pt}

\newcommand{\activity}[4] { %
  \hline \hourFormat{\theMinsIntoLesson}  \addtocounter{MinsIntoLesson}{#2}  
  \rule[\dimexpr9pt-#2\hunits\relax]{0pt}{#2\hunits} &  #1  &  #4  &  #3  \\ \hline % \begin{activity}
}

\newenvironment{activ}[4]{ 
  #1  &  #2  &  #3  &  #4  % \begin{activity}
}{}

\def\hi{Hello, this is my own package}

\let\myDate\date

\newcommand\GoodBye[1][\bfseries]{#1Good Bye}

\endinput

%%
%% End of file `lessonPlanner.sty'.
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed.  Fixed.  Many thanks.